# How to tell Vim not to try to unzip a file?

Tags: filetype, binary-file, plugin-zip

I'm trying to open an `.xlsx` file in Vim, but got an error saying:

```
***error*** (zip#Browse) unzip not available on your system
```

I know it's a binary file, but I want to do some checksums and probably convert to hex.

I noticed that if I change the extension, Vim no longer tries to unzip it. Which leads me to my question:

Is there a way to tell Vim to open a file without attempting to unzip it?

FWIW, I'm using Vim 7.4 under Windows 7.

Comment: I get the same error on my Linux system, so it doesn't seem to be Windows-specific behaviour

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you doing your checksums/hex from within vim?

Comment: @Random832 on this occasion, just because it's the first thing that came to my mind. Most other times, because I can checksum a [range](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Ranges) instead of the whole file, and hex because I can switch back and forth with raw.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Functionality like this is handled by [autocmds](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_40.txt.html#40.3).  In order to disable autocmds for a specific command, you can use `:noautocmd` (abbreviated `:noau`).  In this case

```
:noau e foo.xlsx
```

will simply open the raw file rather than triggering the autocmds that try to open the zip file.

You can also use this from your shell:

```
$ vim -c 'noau e foo.xlsx'
```

If you want more granularity than disabling all autocmds, you could temporarily disable the `BufRead`/`BufReadPre` autocmds using the [`'eventignore'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27eventignore%27) option.

```
:set ei=BufRead,BufReadPre
:e foo.xlsx
:set ei=
```

Comment: Is it also possible to disable just the `autocmd`/`augroup` as defined by the zip plugin? I like this (+1), but if you for example have an `autocmd` to disable syntax highlight and such for large files (as is common), then you will *also* disable that as a side-effect...

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Not temporarily.  If you know the group name (in this case "zip"), you can undefine all of the autocmds defined in that group with `augroup zip | exe 'au!' | augroup END`.

Answer (score 12):

This seems to the the "zip" plugin, which is shipped with Vim and enabled by default.

[`:help zip`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pi_zip.txt.html) has some information about it, among other things:

> PREVENTING LOADING
>
> If for some reason you do not wish to use vim to examine zipped files,
>    you may put the following two variables into your <.vimrc> to prevent
>    the zip plugin from loading:
>
> ```
> let g:loaded_zipPlugin= 1                                               
> let g:loaded_zip      = 1
> ```

After adding these 2 lines, I'm able to open a `.zip` file as any other file.

I didn't know about this either, by the way; but the error message mentioned `zip#Browse`, so I just typed `:help zip` and landed on the right documentation page :-)

See [How do I navigate to topics in Vim's documentation?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2136/how-do-i-navigate-to-topics-in-vims-documentation) for some more information & tips about Vim's help system.

This will also work for the `tar` plugin, except you use `g:loaded_tarPlugin` & `g_loaded_tar`.

Comment: That does the trick. Too bad I can't +2 for linking to the documentation question.

Comment: @Roflo I can't take any credit for that post, that's all *romainl*'s work :-)