# How can I use Vim as a hex editor?

Tags: binary-file

Is there a neat way I can view binary files as hex in Vim, and save it back to binary from the hex?

Answer (score 251):

You can use the `xxd` command to transform a file in Vim to hex representation, doing

`:%!xxd`

`:` enters command-line mode, `%` matches whole file as a range, `!` filters that range through an external command, `xxd` is that external shell command

Giving an output like this, this is split into octet count/line (octets per line may be changed with parameter `-c` on `xxd` command), hex representation, and text representation:

```
0000000: 5468 6973 2069 7320 6120 7465 7374 0a41  This is a test.A
0000010: 6e6f 7468 6572 206c 696e 650a 416e 6420  nother line.And 
0000020: 7965 7420 616e 6f74 6865 720a            yet another.
```

Once you make the changes (in the hex part), you can go back to text with `-r` command on xxd, so

`:%!xxd -r`

This is a little rudimentary, though I like it in its simplicity and to keep in mind `xxd`, which is an interesting command line tool (I don't have to do a lot of work on hex, though). You can use some recipes to handle this transformation in a more automatic way like the one described in *[Improved hex editing](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Improved_hex_editing)*.

And rembember you can also use syntax highlighting for hex editing in vim with that command:

```
:set ft=xxd
```

Comment: I think it worths mentioning that after you make the changes you **must** go back to the normal mode before saving the changes.

Comment: Is it possible to specify the byte order? big-endian or little-endian

Comment: BTW. Where is `:h` for `:%!`? I could find only for `:!`. Using nvim.

Comment: Info: After changing a hex code in the middle of a file and finally comparing it with "Beyond Compare" I found out that `vim` added `0A` to the end of the file. So it now has a different size (+ 1 Byte). I think a hex editor should not do such things. I used `truncate --size=-1` to correct this.

Comment: Is there a plugin or other way that shows the connection between the bytes in hex format and decoded to ASCII? For example, when the cursor is at byte `54` it would highlight the `T`. Similar to how [`hexedit`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/hexedit) does it. Edit: [this plugin](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=666) should do it.

Comment: @SubinSebastian yes, just look at the -e and -g options of the xxd manual http://man.he.net/?topic=xxd&section=all

Comment: As this thread was higher in the google search results (compared to the other duplicate thread it suggest), thought I'd highlight something from that other thread, that it's worth performing `:set binary` prior to doing `:%!xdd`, to assure (at least in windows) that things like EOL chars aren't altered. E.g. for me, it was switching every `0x0a` into `0x0d 0x0a` unless I did the `:set binary` step first.

Also worth noting that to make it display the more common (to me) byte-fields, do `%!xdd -g 1`

Answer (score 30):

Taken from `:h hex-editing`:

```
If one has a particular extension that one uses for binary files (such as exe,
bin, etc), you may find it helpful to automate the process with the following
bit of autocmds for your <.vimrc>.  Change that "*.bin" to whatever
comma-separated list of extension(s) you find yourself wanting to edit:

" vim -b : edit binary using xxd-format!
augroup Binary
  au!
  au BufReadPre  *.bin let &bin=1
  au BufReadPost *.bin if &bin | %!xxd
  au BufReadPost *.bin set ft=xxd | endif
  au BufWritePre *.bin if &bin | %!xxd -r
  au BufWritePre *.bin endif
  au BufWritePost *.bin if &bin | %!xxd
  au BufWritePost *.bin set nomod | endif
augroup END
```

You may want to look at: [How do I navigate to topics in Vim's documentation?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2136/778)

Comment: This is perfect - I added it to `~/.vim/plugin/binary.vim`

Comment: Maybe this is must be in `~/.vim/ftdetect/` because this is about file type detection?

Comment: You can add `silent` to avoid "hit enter to continue", and `getpos` and `setpos` to keep the current cursor position. That way it is easy to just save and check the asc-ii code.