# What does [count]% do?

Tags: cursor-movement, count

I would expect `[count]%` to jump back and forth between matching braces `count` times or something like that, but instead, typing that command seems to move the cursor to a random place in the buffer.  It seems to always go to the same place for constant `count`, but different places for different `count`. So what exactly does that command do?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From [`:help N%`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#N%25):

> Go to `{count}` percentage in the file, on the first non-blank in the line `|linewise|`.  To compute the new line number this formula is used:
>   (`{count}` * number-of-lines + 99) / 100
>   See also `'startofline'` option.

I didn't know this either, by the way. But I typed `:help %<C-d>`, and `N%` looked like a good match ;-)

Also see: [How do I navigate to topics in Vim's documentation?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2136/51).

Answer (score 2):

#### [Plugin Match-Up](https://github.com/andymass/vim-matchup): `g:matchup_motion_override_Npercent`

This plugin offers the possibility to use `[count]%` for both motions:

> - `{count}%` forwards `{count}` times. Requires `{count} <= g:matchup_motion_override_Npercent`.
> - For larger `{count}`, `{count}%` goes to the `{count}` percentage in the file.

The default value is `6`.

This means
`5%` would cycle five `b:match_words`, e.g. in vimscript through `elseif`.
But `50%` would jump to the middle of the file.