# How can I find the list of all of vim's default keybindings?

Tags: key-bindings

Where can I find a list of all the default *vim* key bindings/mappings? Something like this [alphabetical listing for vi](http://hea-www.harvard.edu/~fine/Tech/vi.html), but specifically for vim, not vi.

I know that I can use `:map`, `:imap`, `:nmap`, etc, however these show me the mappings based on my current configuration. I'm aware of [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/6834/how-to-find-out-what-a-key-is-mapped-to), but don't believe it to be a duplicate because it is about the current mappings *based upon* the user's configuration. I'm specifically looking for the *default mappings*.

How do I see the defaults?