# How to get info on set cc=number?

Tags: vimscript

```
set cc=10
```

The simple command for vim version greater than 7.3 can create a red line from top till bottom on the 10th column.
I want to get more info about "set cc=number" such as 'can make the line to be green'?
What file or function or code blocks are called when to input `set cc=10` in ex mode?

Comment: :help hl-ColorColumn or :hi ColorColumn should give you some information

Comment: [`:help 'cc'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27cc%27) ... Also see: [How do I navigate to topics in Vim's documentation?](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2136/51)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get info on just `set cc` try `:help 'cc'`

There is a lot to talk about on the subject of highlighting.. The reason that I say this is because I am the author of a highlighting plugin and I went through the ringer trying to understand and master the art of highlighting.

My plugin is called [vim-poi](https://github.com/DanBradbury/vim-poi) and has been rewritten once from the original implementation (I'm still torn on which solution I like better but for the purposes of learning highlighting it should be enough to get started)

`'cc'` can do some cool thing. Taking a look at `:help 'cc'` as Carpetsmoker mentioned we can see that this is just  highlighting under the covers

> 'colorcolumn' 'cc'    string  (default "")
>
> ```
>       local to window             {not in Vi}             {not available when compiled
> ```
>
> without the |+syntax|             feature}
>
> 'colorcolumn' is a comma separated list of screen columns that are
>     highlighted with ColorColumn |hl-ColorColumn|.  Useful to align
>     text.  Will make screen redrawing slower.   The screen column can be
>   an absolute number, or a number preceded with     '+' or '-', which is
>   added to or subtracted from 'textwidth'. >
>
> ```
>   :set cc=+1  " highlight column after 'textwidth'        :set cc=+1,+2,+3
> ```
>
> " highlight three columns after 'textwidth'       :hi ColorColumn
>   ctermbg=lightgrey guibg=lightgrey

The TLDR of all this is to learn highlighting (`:help hi`). I'd definitely play around with some more complex `cc`s and get used to navigating `:hi` (list of all active highlights) and understanding where they all come from (colorschemes, plugins, etc.)

If you want to read about more of my struggles with more advanced highlighting read [here](http://danbradbury.net/blog/2015/07/15/matchadd-vs-match/) (`match`/`2match` vs `matchadd` struggles)