# What does "tag" mean in the context of Vim's help window?

Tags: help-system, tags

I ran `:help index` to find out about key mappings and it's great, but there's one thing I don't get. At the top it says...

> This file contains a list of all commands for each mode, **with a tag** and a
>   short description.

Indeed, the leftmost column of information in each section is "tag".

So e.g., the first thing is...

```
tag             char            action in Insert mode
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
i_CTRL-@        CTRL-@          insert previously inserted text and stop
```

What is the nature and purpose of the tag `i_CTRL-@`?

Does it do something useful I should know about?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The tag is useful for two things:

1. When using the [`:help`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/helphelp.txt.html#%3Ahelp) command, the tag is the exact phrase which will let you distinguish between similar terms.

   ```
                                                   {subject} E149 E661
   :h[elp] {subject}       Like ":help", additionally jump to the tag {subject}.
   ```

   For example, `<c-A>` is available in insert, normal and command-line modes. To get to the help entry for:

   - insert mode, do `:h i_CTRL-A`.
   - normal mode, do `:h CTRL-A`.
   - command-line mode, do `:h c_CTRL-A`.
2. You can use them for tag navigation. From [`:h tags`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/tagsrch.txt.html#tag):

   ```
   With the ":tag" command the cursor will be positioned on the tag.  With the
   CTRL-] command, the keyword on which the cursor is standing is used as the
   tag.  If the cursor is not on a keyword, the first keyword to the right of the
   cursor is used.
   ```

   So, when on a tag, you can press [`<c-]>`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/tagsrch.txt.html#CTRL-%5D) to jump to where the tag is defined, which is where the full help for that entry will be present. For example, in the list you show, if you move to `i_CTRL-A` and press `<c-]>`, you'll [get to](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/insert.txt.html#i_CTRL-%40):

   ```
                                                   i_CTRL-@
   CTRL-@          Insert previously inserted text and stop insert.  {Vi: only
                   when typed as first char, only up to 128 chars}
   ```

   And you can press [`<c-T>`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/tagsrch.txt.html#CTRL-T) to jump back to where you were.

---

See also: points 6 and 9 in [this excellent answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/2137/205) about the help system.