# Understanding the line() built-in function

Tags: vimscript

I'm reading vim help about the line function and here is an example I found:

```
:let failed = append(line('$'), "# THE END")
```

In my vimrc I also found `line('.')`. The documentation says:

> `line( {expr})`           Number  line nr of cursor, last line or mark

I tried to invoke it as

```
:echo :call line('$')
```

but this printed the following error:

```
E121: Undefined variable: :call
E15: Invalid expression: :call line('$')
```

What does `'.'` and `'$'` mean here and how to invoke it correctly?

Comment: What doc have you read? If you found [`:h line()`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#line()) the 3rd and 4th lines describes what `.` and `$` means.

Comment: @statox `:h functions`. Didn't think there were docs for each function,

Comment: One of the strength of Vim is that everything is documented you might be interested in reading [this question](http://vi.stackexchange.com/a/2137/1841)

Comment: The whole idea with calling functions syntax is: if you use the returned value, you don't need to use `call`; but, if you are just calling the function, then you need to use `call`. So, `:echo line('$')` or `:call line('$')`, but not `:echo :call line('$')`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In `:help line` all possible values of `{expr}` are explained:

```
.       the cursor position                                 
$       the last line in the current buffer                 
'x      position of mark x (if the mark is not set, 0 is returned)                                           
w0      first line visible in current window                
w$      last line visible in current window                 
v       In Visual mode: the start of the Visual area (the   
        cursor is the end).  When not in Visual mode        
        returns the cursor position.  Differs from '< in    
        that it's updated right away.
```

And to invoke that you just need:

```
:echo line('.')
```

`call` is for running functions:

```
function! func()
    echo line('.')
endfunction
```

If you would have something like that in your `.vimrc`, then you could use `call` like so: `:call func()`

Comment: For both '.' and '$' line() returns 1 for an empty file. It also returns 1 for a file that contains just a single newline character. Is there any way to tell the difference?