# What are the .viminfo and .netrwhist files?

Tags: viminfo

I was wondering what's the purpose of .viminfo and .netrwhist files?

Comment: Do you know there is a doc in Vim? We even have a [really good question](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2136/1841) to help you using it...

Comment: When in doubt: just try `:h <any-word>`. At least half the time you'll find what you're looking for. :-)

Comment: `h: netrw-u`, `h: netrw-U`, `h: netrw-Th`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9850360/what-is-netrwhist

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can see that here:

[`:h viminfo`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/starting.txt.html#viminfo)

> If you exit Vim and later start it again, you would normally lose a lot of information.  The viminfo file can be used to remember that information, which enables you to continue where you left off.

[`:h .netrwhist`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pi_netrw.txt.html#.netrwhist)

> The file ".netrwhist" holds history when netrw (and vim) is not
>   active.