# Reset state of a file

Tags: vimrc

I know that vim retains some meta information about a file (like cursor position before you last closed it, file type if you have manually set it)

How can I reset this information? I'm in a very weird situation where I have a file `x` and I have a file `y` that is just a symlink to `x`.

I'm getting a weird error whenever I try to edit `y` but I don't encounter it when editing `x` directly, indicating that this has something to do with the file state rather than the error being legitimate (error message is about a plugin but removing that plugin doesn't stop vim from trying to invoke functions in that plugin in the file `y`, though it does not give any error in file `x` or any other symlinks of `x`)

How do I just reset the file `y`? I've tried deleting and restoring it, to no avail. I cannot rename it, it's a configuration file so it must be present in a certain location.

---

Answers to some follow up questions:

1. Are the file extensions same? Yes, and so is `:set ft?`.
2. Are any plugins that save / restore session state? I have inspected the plugins and does not seem that's the case
3. Is `:scriptnames` same between both the files? Yes

Comment: Note: I couldn't find an appropriate tag for this question, edits welcome

Comment: Try deleting the .viminfo file in your home directory, though I have doubts about this being the cause: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/10671/what-are-the-viminfo-and-netrwhist-files

Comment: What plugin functions does Vim try to invoke?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @EndreBoth remove from where? removing `~/.viminfo` does not seem to reset file state (vim still remembers last edit position).

Comment: @EndreBoth and @Rich it's `error detected while processing function AutoPairsInsert: line 1: E121: Undefined variable: b:autopairs_enabled` but IMO that's garbage. I removed autopairs extension, removed syntax highlight extension for the file, changed file type, all to no avail

Comment: Use `:scriptnames` from both `x` and `y` to see which Vim scripts get loaded with each and then see whether there's a difference. Do files `x` and `y` have different extensions that would trigger different filetypes? (Also, try `:set ft?` to inspect it with each file.) Do you have any plug-in that's restoring views or sessions? Please [edit] your question to include answers to these follow ups.

Comment: @filbranden done. But honestly I do not want to "debug" this issue any further, I want to first try something that will remove file-related data like "last edit position". `.viminfo` didn't, sadly. Was it supposed to?

Comment: @EndreBoth actually that worked! I don't know, I must have messed up before and not removed the `.viminfo` file (but thought I did). When I did it now, it *did* reset the last edit position and ALSO fixed the issue! You may post it as an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: @PeeyushKushwaha - Hm, I'm still wondering. Filbranden's suggestions seem to make a lot of sense. But at least you've got rid of the error message :).

Comment: I am not completely sure it will work, but have you tried `:bd` on both files? Then reopen them. Then maybe save state `wshada` for nvim.