# What is the vimscript version of sprintf?

Tags: vimscript, string-manipulation

I'm trying to create a dynamic line to `execute`, currently I have

```
execute a:modes[i] .'noremap <silent> <buffer> '. l:key .' <Esc>:call HardModeEcho(g:HardMode_hardmodeMsg)<CR>'
```

I'd like that to be something like

```
execute sprintf( 
  "%snoremap <silent> <buffer> %s <ESC>:call HardModeEcho(g:HardMode_hardmodeMsg)<CR>",
  a:modes[i],
  l:key
)
```

Actually it needs to get even more complex. But, I'd like to start with that. Is there any such functionality in vimscript?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Somewhat surprisingly, it's [`printf()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#printf%28%29), which behaves like `sprintf()` in most other languages.

I wasn't 100% sure what the name was from the top of my head; I found this by just entering `:help printf` :-) I also find [`:help function-list`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_41.txt.html#function-list) to be invaluable when VimScript-ing.

Also see: [How do I navigate to topics in Vim's documentation?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2136/51).

Comment: printf and sprintf aren't the same in any language that I know of, that's interesting. printf doesn't print, it returns a formatted string. I did try, `:help sprintf`, and I looked for it on Google. Didn't know about `function-list`

Comment: Yeah, it's a bit unusual @EvanCarroll, but it makes sense. For a `printf` function to print, you would have to use `:call printf(..)`, which is exactly the same length as `:echo printf(..)`. Not really much value in having such a function, so might as well return a string. Arguably, `sprintf()` would have made been a better name, but OTOH `printf()` saves us one character of typing ;-)

Comment: Ah, because `:call` on a string in void-context is echo. Perhaps that makes some degree of sense, but you don't see that kind of stuff in other languages. Forgive the simple question. I'm just trying to write a quick patch for hardmode.