# variable names prefixed with &

Tags: variables

It seems that `&` followed by an option name is an variable containing the option value, such as `&diff`. What is `&l:diff`. I assume it is the local value for `diff` option, but I cannot find the doc that mentioned this. (I found the example in `fugitive`)

In addition, `diff` is a window-local option and some other options are buffer-local. Do I use the same `l:` for both of them?

Comment: I'm positive I answered this question before, but I can't find the question anywhere :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the same as `setlocal`: it changes a setting for just the current buffer or window, instead of locally. See [`:help :let-&`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#%3Alet-%26) (after you scroll down a bit) and [`:help :setlocal`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%3Asetlocal).

---

Note: in my experience the easiest way to find stuff in Vim's help pages is to enable the `wildmenu` setting and press `:help :let<Tab>` to see which pages exist, and then select the most appropriate one (`:let-&` in this case). Also see [How do I navigate to topics in Vim's documentation?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2136/51).