# Neovim - Map selectively only on a terminal window

Tags: neovim, terminal-buffer

I like the terminal in neovim. I am accustomed to tmux and tmux's copy-mode, and type `q` to exit copy-mode to return back to regular-interactive-mode. Now, in neovim, when in NORMAL mode (which is akin to copy-mode in tmux), I end up typing `q` hoping to get back to INSERT mode, only to realize nothing happening (as neovim dutifully prepares to start recording). I also use macro recording in vim.

So, is there a way to normal-mode-map `q` to `a` only when its a terminal-buffer? And retain `q` for its existing record-macro use in other buffers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I imagine you can use a buffer-local mapping.

```
nnoremap <buffer> q a
```

All you need now is a way to apply it to only terminal buffers. Put the following in your `vimrc` file:

```
augroup MyTermMappings
  autocmd!
  autocmd TermOpen * nnoremap <buffer> q a
augroup END
```

Note: I do not use NeoVim so this is all guesswork.

Comment: I am using Neovim and verified that the above works. However, anyone who can answer why `tnoremap` does not work?

Comment: According to [`:h terminal-input`](https://neovim.io/doc/user/nvim_terminal_emulator.html#terminal-input), `tmap`'s only affect terminal-mode which is when keys are pass to the underlying terminal. Think of terminal mode as a variant insert-mode for terminal buffers.

Comment: Thanks Peter! How did you find the help tag that describes this behaviour? (By the way, I am on Nvim 0.2.0 and the tag is `:h terminal-emulator-input`, for whoever interested to read that part of the manual)

Comment: I only have access to [NeoVim's online docs](https://neovim.io/doc/user/). You should of course use your local help files. I found the doc by searching for equivalent of `:h :term` which lead me to `:h terminal` where I read the `terminal_emulator.txt` help page. Which has the information you are looking  for and the tag. However if I had neovim I would probably do `:h term<c-d>` to list out terminal topics or searched via `:helpgrep terminal`. [How to use `:help`](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/2137/778)

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment, only post an answer, but I'd like to say that the

```
augroup MyTermMappings
  autocmd!
  autocmd TermOpen * nnoremap <buffer> q a
augroup END
```

works but it must go in your `init.vim` file and not your standard `.vimrc` if you use vi/m at all. Putting it into the `.vimrc` file causes a `No such group or event: TermOpen * nnoremap <buffer> ...` error.