# neovim key remap specific to terminal buffer

Tags: key-bindings, neovim, terminal, terminal-buffer

I have been using nvim terminal mode to learn python and I want to have Ctrl-C break the python script from the terminal window even when I am not in insert mode. However, I also want Ctrl-C in my python script to result in entering an escape command directly to the terminal.

I have

```
if exists(':tnoremap')
    nnoremap <C-c> <C-w>wi<C-c><C-\><C-n><C-w>w  
    " Ctrl-c from py sends key interupt to python terminal
end
```

in my .vimrc file which gives me the functionality for sending Ctrl-C to the terminal when I am in the python script buffer.

I have tried
`:tnoremap <C-c> i<C-c>`
which does not work, I think because I am trying to issue the command from normal mode. This is a documented 'feature' of tmap.

I have found that 
`nnoremap <buffer> <C-c> i<C-c>`
works but because the buffer has a name like :term\##:python where ## is the process id, and therefore varies, I cannot figure out how to incorporate the above into my rc file such that the terminal buffer automatically inherits this (local) functionality.

I have tried (from this [answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/14377/neovim-map-selectively-only-on-a-terminal-window))

```
augroup MyTermMappings
  autocmd!
  autocmd TermOpen * nnoremap <buffer> <C-c> i<C-c>
augroup END
```

but this makes my whole rc file crap out with the error `no such group or event TermOpen * nnoremap <buffer>...`

I have also tried changing my launch of the terminal command (which is currently   `nnoremap <leader>r :split \| terminal python<CR> <C-w>w`)
to send the local remap to the command line on launch but all I have been able to accomplish is crashing the python terminal.

I know I can just run the `nnoremap <buffer> <C-c> i<C-c>` after launching terminal but I would like to have any buffer that is launched with :terminal have this command.

Alternatively, I tried having the default behavior be that in normal mode Ctrl-C mapped to enter insert mode and type Ctrl-c e.g. `nnoremap <C-c> i<C-c>` and then further in the .vimrc file `autocmd FileType python nnoremap <buffer> <C-w>wi<C-c><C-\><C-n><C-w>w` but that also did not work.

I think this can be solved using autocmd options in Vim or if the nmap  cmd can take a pattern but I am fairly unfamiliar with these and have not had any luck looking at other responses.

Comment: Why not create an autoloaded function that runs `:term` and sets up your desired mappings, and bind that to a key or command in your python `after/ftplugin` ?

Comment: Tried the `autocmd TermOpen ..` approach, it works. My nvim is v0.3.1.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble could you explain that a bit more? I am a little bit new to all of this

Comment: I can confirm that `autocmd TermOpen ...` does work when I write, save and load in nvim but it does cause the above error when using regular vim.

Comment: @nmb ill try to put together an answer with some different options.

Answer (score 2):

#### Using autocmds

Neovim provides `TermOpen`, while vim provides `TerminalOpen`:

```
augroup MyTermMappings
  autocmd!
  if has('nvim')
    autocmd TermOpen * nnoremap <buffer> <C-c> i<C-c>
  else if exists('##TerminalOpen')
    audocmd TerminalOpen * nnoremap <buffer> <C-c> i<C-c>
  endif
augroup END
```

I've provided another solution, but this is probably simpler and more general.

#### Via function and ftplugin

Write a function in `~/.vim/autoload/terminal.vim` (may need to adjust `~/.vim`
for neovim users):

```
" ~/.vim/autoload/terminal.vim
" The name <terminal.vim> is arbitrary, but affects function declarations
" within
" cf :help autload
function! terminal#python() abort
  terminal python
  " this is the equivalent of <C-w>w
  wincmd w
  nnoremap <buffer> <C-c> i<C-c>
endfunction
```

And bind it to your terminal mapping:

```
" ~/.vim/after/ftplugin/python.vim
" cf
" - :help ftplugin
" - :help after-directory
" (after notes that after is rarely necessary, but I like it to overrule the
" settings)

" Use whatever keys you want
nnoremap <silent> <buffer> <LocalLeader>r :call terminal#python()<CR>

" Don't forget to add to 'b:undo_ftplugin'
" I've got a specialized framework for that over at
" https://github.com/benknoble/Dotfiles/blob/master/links/vim/autoload/ftplugin.vim
" but this is simpler and should work for your purpose
let b:undo_ftplugin = get(b:, 'undo_ftplugin', '')
if ! empty(b:undo_ftplugin)
  let b:undo_ftplugin .= ' | '
endif
let b:undo_ftplugin .= "execute 'silent! nunmap <buffer> <LocalLeader>r'"
```

---

Side Note: your normal mapping for python files could also go in the ftplugin
file above, unless you want it for *all* files.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to my .vimrc seems to have fixed it for my purposes without slowing down vim load or python launch

```
augroup pythonTerminal      " name localized commands so they don'g get
                            " written on every rc read
  autocmd!                  " delete all exisiting au commands in group
  autocmd BufWinEnter,WinEnter term://* nnoremap <buffer> <C-c> i<C-c>
                            " <C-c> interrupts python in terminal normal
  autocmd BufWinEnter,WinEnter *.py :nnoremap <buffer> <C-c> 
      \ <C-w>wi<C-c><C-\><C-n><C-w>w
      " <C-c> kills python terminal running from script file
augroup END
```

I am not sure if I should add all my other python interactive mode commands to this and/or when autocmd is better to use than just the remap command but, to date at least, I haven't run into any issues in either vim or nvim with this snippet.

Thanks to everyone for their help!

Comment: Note that you don't need to add `:` in an autocommand because you are already executing a command. `:` is only needed in normal mode to start command line mode. Also it is normal that `termOpen` doesn't work in Vim since this event is implemented only by neovim.