# vimscript: get result of cmdline-completion Ctrl-a

Tags: vimscript, functions, help-system

Need a function that,

1. returns a string, which is result of cmdline-completion Ctrl-a, i.e.,
   a list of words seperated by space.
2. given an input string of partial ex-command.

For example,

- given `:h bufwin`, return `h bufwinid() bufwinnr() BufWinEnter BufWinLeave`
- given `:call getl`, return `call getline( getloclist(`

**== further clarification ==**

`:h cmdline-completion` has relevant info about `c^a` and `c^f`. (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>f</kbd> in cmdline-mode)

As said in [this answer about find vim-doc efficiently](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/14390/10254)

In normal-mode, type `:h bufwin` then type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd>, will show all completion candidates,
whereas type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>f</kbd> then <kbd>dd</kbd> could manually get the result.

But here what I pursuit is an automated version wrapped in a vimscript function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit:

Sorry, I misunderstood your question. I think you want the `getcompletion()` function.

> For example,
>
> ```
> given :h bufwin, return h bufwinid() bufwinnr() BufWinEnter BufWinLeave
> ```

You could get this with the following invocation of `getcompletion()`:

```
echo getcompletion('*bufwin', 'help')
```

> given `:call getl`, return `call getline( getloclist(`

And you could get this with:

```
echo getcompletion('getl', 'function')
```

The signature of the function is the following:

```
getcompletion({pat}, {type} [, {filtered}])
```

It expects 2 mandatory arguments, and accepts 1 optional one.
The 1st argument is a pattern, which can include some metacharacters like `*` (match any sequence of characters; see `:help wildcard`). The 2nd argument is the type of completion in which you're interested. Currently, there are 33 possible types:

```
augroup         autocmd groups
buffer          buffer names
behave          :behave suboptions
color           color schemes
command         Ex command (and arguments)
compiler        compilers
cscope          |:cscope| suboptions
dir             directory names
environment     environment variable names
event           autocommand events
expression      Vim expression
file            file and directory names
file_in_path    file and directory names in |'path'|
filetype        filetype names |'filetype'|
function        function name
help            help subjects
highlight       highlight groups
history         :history suboptions
locale          locale names (as output of locale -a)
mapclear        buffer argument
mapping         mapping name
menu            menus
messages        |:messages| suboptions
option          options
packadd         optional package |pack-add| names
shellcmd        Shell command
sign            |:sign| suboptions
syntax          syntax file names |'syntax'|
syntime         |:syntime| suboptions
tag             tags
tag_listfiles   tags, file names
user            user names
var             user variables
```

When the 3rd optional argument is passed to the function, and is set to 1, the value of your `'wildignore'` option is taken into consideration to eliminate some of the matches.

If you wanted to capture the completion matches for several types simultaneously, you could try this custom function:

```
fu! s:get_cmdline_candidates(pat, types) abort
    let lists = map(a:types, { i,v -> getcompletion(a:pat, v, 1)})
    let candidates = []
    for a_list in lists
        let candidates += a_list
    endfor
    return uniq(sort(candidates))
endfu
```

Usage example (in a script):

```
let myvar = s:get_cmdline_candidates('*win', ['command', 'function'])
echo myvar
```

This should display all commands and functions containing the keyword `win`.

But all matches are mixed in a single list. If this is an issue, you could try this function instead:

```
fu! s:get_cmdline_candidates(pat, types) abort
    let dicts = map(a:types, { i,v -> { v : getcompletion(a:pat, v, 1) }})
    call filter(dicts, {i,v -> !empty(v)})
    let candidates = {}
    for a_dict in dicts
        call extend(candidates, a_dict)
    endfor
    return candidates
endfu
```

Usage example:

```
let myvar = s:get_cmdline_candidates('*win', ['command', 'function'])
echo myvar
```

This time, `myvar` contains a dictionary with 2 keys, `'command'` and `'function'`, whose values are the associated completion matches for the pattern `*win`. You can access the commands with `myvar.command`, and the functions with `myvar.function`.

---

> How to silently ignore failed calls of `getcompletion()`?

If you think an error may occur, you could use a `try` conditional to catch and ignore it. Example `1` (the output will be a list):

```
fu! s:get_cmdline_candidates(pat, types) abort
    let candidates = []
    for a_type in a:types
        try
            let candidates += getcompletion(a:pat, a_type, 1)
        catch
        endtry
    endfor
    return uniq(sort(candidates))
endfu
```

Example `2` (the output will be a dictionary):

```
fu! s:get_cmdline_candidates(pat, types) abort
    let candidates = {}
    for a_type in a:types
        try
            call extend(candidates, { a_type: getcompletion(a:pat, a_type, 1)})
        catch
        endtry
    endfor
    return candidates
endfu
```

---

Note that you need a Vim version more recent than [7.4.2011](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v7.4.2011), since it's the patch where `getcompletion()` was added in Vim.

For more information, see `:help getcompletion()`.

---

*Old answer*

I came up with this code:

```
cno <silent> <expr> <c-x><c-d> '<c-a>'.<sid>capture_cmdline_candidates()

fu! s:capture_cmdline_candidates() abort
    call timer_start(0, {-> setreg('"', getcmdline(), 'l')
    \                     + feedkeys("\<c-c>", 'int') })
    return ''
endfu
```

It installs a mapping using the key sequence `C-x C-d`, but you could change it for whatever else you like.

When you press it, the `s:capture_cmdline_candidates()` function should populate the unnamed register (`@"`) with all the candidates which would have been written on the command line if you had pressed `C-a`. It also makes you directly quit the command line, so that you can put the contents of the unnamed register in the buffer you want, by pressing `p`.

---

Actually, you could eliminate the function:

```
cno <silent> <expr> <c-x><c-d> '<c-a>'.timer_start(0, {-> setreg('"', getcmdline(), 'l') + feedkeys('<c-c>', 'int') })[-1]
```

---

You could also try this mapping:

```
cno <silent> <expr> <c-x><c-d> '<c-a>'.&cedit.'dd:q<cr>'
```

But when I tested it, the brief appearance of the command line window was a little distracting, because its name was displayed in the tabline.

Comment: I tried in a plain session `vim -N -u NONE +"so test.vim"`, but not work. Or am I missing something in the workflow? could you plz elaborate a little on the workflow with a concrete example?

Comment: Also better if I just call a function in the background, and don't have to manually type the command prefix in cmdline-mode, just pass it as argument.

Comment: I have a mapping similar to `nn  <F2> :exec getline(".")<CR>`, and use it run line under cursor as ex-command, eg, call a function, or run a chain of command. Which is in my note file of vim.

Comment: Also, the initial interactive cmap approach is quite helpful & illuminating too.

Comment: Simple `abort` the function is perhaps not appropriate here. eg, it will fail if passing a list of all 33 string as `types`. **How to silently ignore failed calls of getcompletion()?** Otherwise it works perfectly, thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 2):

Nowadays we have no reason to play with `c_CTRL-A` as we have `getcompletion()`. See @user852573's answer.

In the past, however, we had to

1. create a dummy command with the completion mode we're interested into
2. inject that command and the leading parameter in the command line
3. ask to see all the possible completions (with `c_CTRL-A`),
4. surround the new command-line with `let g:whatever="` and `"`
5. and finally execute.

Then the `whatever` global variable would contain the name of the dummy command and all possible completions.

There were a few caveats: double-quotes could mess the result.

To fix that, we could then use `getcmdline()`. Alas to use it in the flow we had to inject a new cmapping that could add noise when the objective is to find mapppings -- I had the issue.

The result is in my [library plugin](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib/blob/master/autoload/lh/command.vim#L133):

```
" Function: lh#command#matching_askvim(what, lead) {{{3
if exists('*getcompletion')
  function! lh#command#matching_askvim(what, lead) abort
    return getcompletion(a:lead, a:what)
  endfunction
else
  function! lh#command#matching_askvim(what, lead) abort
    let cleanup = lh#on#exit()
          \.register('delcom LHAskVimMatchingCompletion')
    try
      exe 'command! -complete='.a:what.' -nargs=* LHAskVimMatchingCompletion :echo "<args>"'
      if exists('*getcmdline')
        call cleanup
              \.restore('g:cmds')
              \.restore_buffer_mapping('µ', 'c')
              \.restore_mapping_and_clear_now('<c-a>', 'c')
        cnoremap <buffer> <expr> µ s:register()
        function! s:register()
          let g:cmds = split(getcmdline(), ' ')[1:]
          return ''
        endfunction
        silent! exe "norm :LHAskVimMatchingCompletion ".a:lead."\<c-a>µ"
        return g:cmds
      else
        " The following may lead to problem with unescaped quotes => use
        " getcmdline() when available
        silent! exe "norm! :LHAskVimMatchingCompletion ".a:lead."\<c-a>\"\<home>let\ cmds=\"\<cr>"
        return split(cmds, ' ')[1:]
      endif
    finally
      call cleanup.finalize()
    endtry
  endfunction
endif
```