# Character class to match "iskeyword" characters

Tags: regular-expression, keyword

In short: how do I define a regex that matches `'iskeyword'`.

My initial thought was that `match(str, '\w*')` would match an arbitrary number of keyword characters in `str`, but it really only matches to a predefined list (as confirmed by `:h \w`). Of course, I could manually make up a target with `[]`, but that does not feel right. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [`:h /character-classes`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2fcharacter-classes) you are looking for `\k`:

```
    magic   nomagic matches ~
/\k \k      \k      keyword character (see 'iskeyword' option)
/\K \K      \K      like "\k", but excluding digits
```

Also `\w` matches "word" characters (i.e. `[0-9A-Za-z_]`) as in opposition to "WORD" characters. The difference is explained in [`:h word`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#word).

Comment: Perfect! That is precisely what I was looking for. I still have a hard time finding the right places in the help. Thanks for the pointer to there as well.

Comment: @Octaviour You're welcome! You might also want to have a look at [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2136/how-do-i-navigate-to-topics-in-vims-documentation) romainl's answer contains some pretty good bits of advice.

Comment: Just FYI, there's potential for confusion when using the word "word" in relation to `\w` compared to its usage when talking about things like the commands `w`, `e`, etc and whose counterpart is "WORD". The latter is dictated by the `'iskeyword'` setting while `\w` is always the pattern @statox indicates.