# What is the difference between normal mode and command mode in vim?

Tags: normal-mode

I know that normal mode and command mode is same thing but tells different.

[image]

I found this in [http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mapping_keys_in_Vim_-*Tutorial*(Part_1)](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mapping_keys_in_Vim_-_Tutorial_(Part_1))

Comment: Based on you last two question I strongly suggest that you read [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2136/1841). The built-in documentation of vim is one of the best documentation systems I know and knowing how to use it will definitely save you some time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*command mode* and *command-line mode* must not be confused.
command-line mode is also called *ex-mode*.
You are in command-line mode when you press `:` or `Q`

Comment: @black.swordsman your added text isn't really appropriate for an edit as it seems you've just pasted in a bunch of text from Vim help. This answer's author probably doesn't want that. And actually pasting in chunks of documentation doesn't work as a separate, standalone answer either. If you want to create a _new_ answer containing a link to that help section along with a summary of things in  _your own words_ then that's a better choice. Thanks for participating.