# :put at the end of the current line?

Tags: key-bindings

I like to take minutes for meetings using vim+Markdown(CommonMark)

I like having something like this

```
# Meeting Name - 2018-02-25
```

The way I accomplish this is

```
i# Meeting Name - ^[:put =strftime('%F')<cr>kJ
```

Is there a better way? I know you can do `:-1put ...` and it will put things on the *previous* line, but is there a way to `:put` at the end of the line? (obviously I could make a macro/map, but is there a better way with just put?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why stick to put?

There is a nice alternative to it, like :

`i#Meeting Name - ^R=strftime("%F")<cr>`

btw: Your example seems to be missing a `<cr>` after the `)`

Comment: It might be worth to link to [`:h i_CTRL-R`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/insert.txt.html#i_CTRL-R) and specifically [`:h i_CTRL-R_=`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/insert.txt.html#i_CTRL-R_%3d)

Comment: Nice! This totally works - I hadn't heard of `^r` - and @statox thanks for linking to that docs, because that's *way* more useful than I imagined! There are a number of times that I've done <yank something>`itype some things <esc>pAtype some more things`.

Comment: @WayneWerner Actually everything is in the doc, once you read it you (almost) don't need this site anymore ;) Have a look at [this excellent question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2136/1841) about how to navigate in the doc, it might save you a lot of googling in the future.