# What is the difference between ^ and _ for cursor movement

Tags: cursor-movement, normal-mode

They both seem to move the cursor to the first non-blank character of the current line and I wonder what was the reason for duplicating this functionality

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hello and welcome to this site!

`:help left-right-motions` is your friend here.

The difference is that `_` accepts a `[count]` *before* it, citing the manual:

```
_  <underscore>         [count] - 1 lines downward, on the first non-blank
                        character linewise.
```

while:

```
^                       To the first non-blank character of the line.
                        exclusive motion.
```

Obviously, `_` by itself is equivalent to `1_`, so the outcome is *0 lines downward, on the first non-blank character linewise*, which means the current line (just like `^`).

Comment: @lox You might also want to read [this](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2136/1841) to get better at using Vim's documentation