# Error detected during LaTeX-Suite-aka-Vim-LaTeX plugin update with Vundle

Tags: plugin-vim-latex, plugin-vundle

When updating vundle-managed plugins with: `:PluginUpdate` in buffer, I get the following error message:

```
Error detected while processing
~/.vim/bundle/LaTeX-Suite-aka-Vim-LaTeX/plugin/remoteOpen.vim: line 33
E174: Command already exists: add ! to replace it
```

[image]

I have the queasy feeling that I may well have installed this the wrong way. I did:

- git-cloned [`LaTeX-Suite-aka-Vim-LaTeX`](https://github.com/vim-scripts/LaTeX-Suite-aka-Vim-LaTeX.git) in `~/.vim/bundle/` and then ran `:PluginInstall` in a vim buffer.
- added the line: `Plugin 'vim-scripts/LaTeX-Suite-aka-Vim-LaTeX'`
  between `call vundle#begin()` and `call vundle#end()` in my `~/.vimrc` and sourced `.vimrc`,
- ran `:PluginUpdate` in buffer

Can someone please help me with this issue?

Comment: I was under the impression that you didnt need to git clone if using Vundle? Never used it, but...

Comment: @D.BenKnoble: you are right of course, the point being in that particular trivial case, that I actually did NOT know whether the two plugins (the one on GitHub and the other one available through Vundle) were one and the same. So I tried both and it turns out in that case that importing through the Vundle facility with `:InstallPlugin` or through a _regelrecht_ `$ git clone ...` cmd in terminal gives you rigorously the same result. In fact the issue had nothing to do with that. As pointed out in the answer one of the plugin's internals needs a little bit of dusting....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you read the error message you can see that the problem comes from `~/.vim/bundle/LaTeX-Suite-aka-Vim-LaTeX/plugin/remoteOpen.vim` on line 33. This line is the following:

```
com -nargs=1 RemoteOpen :call RemoteOpen('<args>')
```

It uses [`:h :command`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#%3acommand) to create the user defined command `:RemoteOpen`.

What Vim says is `Command already exists: add ! to replace it`. It says that because when you do `:PluginUpdate` the plugin is sourced again and as [`:h E174`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#E174) says:

```
:com[mand][!] [{attr}...] {cmd} {rep}
            Define a user command.  The name of the command is
            {cmd} and its replacement text is {rep}.  The command's
            attributes (see below) are {attr}.  If the command
            already exists, an error is reported, unless a ! is
            specified, in which case the command is redefined.
```

So an easy fix for you is to replace the line by

```
com! -nargs=1 RemoteOpen :call RemoteOpen('<args>')
```

Also maybe it would be worth it to contact the mainteners and see if they can fix that.

Comment: +1. Thanks, in particular (but not only) because I had not realized that one could parse the help docs for error codes, e.g. `:h E174`. Quite useful.  +  Already contacted plugin's maintainers about the software vagaries in question...

Comment: @Cbhihe Then you might also want to read [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2136/1841) about how to use the doc :)