# g! vs v in vim command

Tags: command-line

Is there any difference between doing the following two commands:

```
:1,19g!/let/d
```

And:

```
:1,19v/let/d
```

Or is `v` an alias for `g!` ?

Comment: You will get your answer instantly if you how how to use the built in help, I suggest you read this [post](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2136/how-do-i-navigate-to-topics-in-vims-documentation).

Comment: @dedowsdi yea it takes me a good deal of time to navigate their docs, for example: `E149: Sorry, no help for g!`, and `v` brings up visual mode.

Comment: Make sure you spend enough time to read it, try it,  there is also `:h {subject}`, no one can use vim properly without knowing how to use the `:h`, it should always be your first choice when you have questions.

Comment: It might take a lot of time to know `:h`, but trust me, it's totally worth it, it's one of the most used command for all vimmers.

Comment: @David542 If you're looking for help on Ex commands you need to include the `:`, you need `:help :v`. The `!` version is documented together with the original, so it will be under `:help :g`.

Comment: David542: yeah make sure you read that post @dedowsdi linked in the comment, it's a great primer on how to use Vim's help effectively!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they're the same.

As [`:help :v`](https://vimhelp.org/repeat.txt.html#%3Av) says:

> Same as `:g!`.

(That's the whole contents of that help entry.)

You'll find the description for `:g!` under [`:help :g`](https://vimhelp.org/repeat.txt.html#%3Ag), just below the description of `:g` itself:

> `:[range]g[lobal]!/{pattern}/[cmd]`
>
> > Execute the Ex command `[cmd]` (default `:p`) on the lines within `[range]` where `{pattern}` does **NOT** match.