# vim input function with default value

Tags: vimrc, vimscript

I'm working a function to rename the visual selected text

```
function! Rename()
    name = getline("'<")[getpos("'<")[2]-1:getpos("'>")[2]-1]
    let newname = input('rename the selection with: ')
    execute ":%s/\\<".name."\\>/".newname."/g"
endfunction
```

Is it possible to have the content of `name` as the the default value of the `input()` function? To be more specific, I'd like to have the command line become (take `name` content to be `ibasis` for example)

```
rename the selection with: ibasis
```

when I call this function. I can then use my mapping `<C-a>` to go to the start of `ibasis`, delete `i` and quickly get the desired result of replacing `ibasis` with `basis`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [`:h input()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#input%28%29)

```
input({prompt} [, {text} [, {completion}]])     *input()*

If the optional {text} argument is present and not empty, this
is used for the default reply, as if the user typed this.
Example: >

     :let color = input("Color? ", "white")
```

Comment: Thanks! I will read the `:help` documentation first in the future.

Comment: @KevinPowell I can't stress enough how useful it is to read the help, it answers 95% of the questions you can have about vim. If you are not familiar with the help you definitely want to read [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2136/1841) to get the basic in 5 minutes :)

Comment: I'm missing the basic of using `help`. Thanks a lot for the link!