# Usage of t. and | in vim command

Tags: vimscript

I've assembled the following command to take a markdown file and add a `====` under  each line that starts with a `#`:

```
:g/^#/t. | s/./=/g
```

How exactly does this work? As far as I understand:

- `:g/` start a global command
- `^#/` where the line starts with a `#`
- `/t.` (not sure what this is or does, had trouble finding it in help)
- `|` (also not quite sure exactly how this works, I've seen a few different examples of this)
- `s/./=/g` substitute every character (`.`) with a `=`

Any clarification/pointers on the above two components of the commands would be great.

Comment: See `:h :t` and `:h :bar`. Important feature when searching for help is `<C-d>`. Just enter `:h |<C-d>`, it will show any help topics that contains the word `bar` (Vim is automatically replacing `|` with `bar`). Less helpful with `:h t<C-d>` I have to admit :-).

Comment: @Ralf -- cool, thanks for that tip. Now clear on the `t` ==> alias for `co[py]`. Still working through `.` and `|` -- there are lots of references for them in the docs...

Comment: The `:t` -> `:copy` seems to be historical. It's also in original vi. And: `:h :.`. David, I don't want to annoy you with all the "see help", but the help of Vim is really good and extensive. It is sometimes a little bit difficult to find the right help subject. Another cool feature is `:helpgrep` to search through the help files.

Comment: @Ralf sure, I appreciate you pointing that out. Out of curiosity, why do you do `:h :.` instead of just `:h .` (which is what I was doing previously)?

Comment: You are using `.` with a (ex-)command, so the leading colon means "dot on the command line". Like the different between `:h bar` and `:h :bar`. Sometimes also with leading `c_` like `:help c_<CR>`.

Comment: @David542 Simply `:h .` means "give me help about "dot" in Normal mode", i.e. repeat-operator. While `:h :.` means "say what is "dot" in the command-line?" Just read the main topic `<F1>` - right after the words "Get specific help" there are several examples, and also the link to `:h help-summary` which gives full explanation.

Comment: And another: :help help.txt`. The start of that file explains the different prefixes used with help subjects.

Comment: See [How do I navigate to topics in Vim's documentation?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2136/18609)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command `:to` is a synonym of `:copy` that can be abbreviated to `:t`. So `:[range]t.` is a short way of saying copy the lines in the range to the current line.

The `|` is the command separator; it’s a bit like a semicolon in most C-like languages. See `:help :bar`.