# Searching a log file using vi or view

Tags: search, original-vi

When I open a log file in vi or view and I need to search for a word, the first thing I do is to press <kbd>G</kbd> to get to the bottom. Then I'll start a search using a <kbd>/</kbd> followed by whatever word I'm looking for. This usually works for me.

Today someone mentioned I should use <kbd>?</kbd> to start my search since I'm starting at the bottom of the file and this will cause it to search from the bottom up.

My question is should I have been using the <kbd>?</kbd> all along, since these are log files and I will usually want to find the most recent occurrence of the "word"?

Also where does the search start when using the <kbd>/</kbd>, from the top or the current line the cursor is on?

Comment: If the cursor is at the beginning of the file don't need to even use `G` (_if_ you have wrapping enabled). Just hit `?`. Otherwise, yeah, `G?` works.

Comment: @filbranden that was the info I was looking for, thanks.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! You might like [How to navigate `:help`](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2136/how-do-i-navigate-to-topics-in-vims-documentation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `/` will search forward and `?` will search backward.

Both will (by default) wrap around when they get to the bottom/top of the file.

To find the most recent occurrence of the search pattern in a log file, you typically want to use `?`, to search backward, wrapping at the top and starting from the bottom of the file.

Unless you have a match on the very last line, using `G` is not necessary. In fact, it might make you miss a match, having the backward search start at the beginning of the last line of the file, rather than also search for the match on that last line.