# How to pass custom arguments to the shell invoked by :terminal?

Tags: neovim, command-line, terminal, external-command, shell

I would like to specify the startup command to run on the `:terminal` shell. E.g. `bash -c ls`. The shell can be specified with `set shell=bash`, but how to specify the arguments? In another use case, I need to specify the shell used by WSL on Windows (`wsl -e fish`) with `set shell=wsl` (which currently opens `bash` by default).

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! In general, `:help :terminal` contains lots of helpful details. You might also be interested in [How to navigate `:help`](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2136/how-do-i-navigate-to-topics-in-vims-documentation)

Comment: you can check for `$VIM_TERMINAL` at the end of `.bashrc` and run the commands there

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with `:terminal $SHELL $CUSTOM $ARGS`.

Comment: I believe you can also do `:terminal ++shell {args}`