# Inserting a future time

Tags: key-bindings

I would like to create a simple pomodoro timer I can insert into text files. Something like:

Current Time - 10:15

End Time - 10:40

However I have not been able to find a good way to insert a future time.

I have used `:put =strftime('%T')` to create the current time and this works perfectly, however I am not sure how to "add" to this time to create a t + 25m time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the current time with `localtime()`:

```
:echo localtime()
1611790246
```

And you can format this with `strftime()` by passing it as the second argument:

```
:echo strftime('%T', localtime())
07:32:16
```

And you can modify it as well:

```
:echo strftime('%T', localtime() + 60 * 25)
07:57:16
```

So for your command it'll be something like:

```
:put =strftime('%T', localtime() + 60 * 25)
```

In reality, you probably want to save the `localtime()` and then insert `strftime('%T', time)` and `strftime('%T', time + 60 * 25)`, because otherwise you might risk the time between the two operations being just long enough for it to be off by one second/minute. You can also round it to 25-minute intervals with some more math.

See `:help localtime()` and `:help strftime()` for more information on all of the above. `:help function-list` is also very useful, which includes a "date and time" section. Also see [How do I navigate to topics in Vim's documentation?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2136/51)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using a system based solution, then on ubuntu (and many linuxes)

```
date --date="5 mins"
```

returns the current time + 5 minutes. You can also ask for hours, days, even "next monday" will give you the date of the next monday.
To load these values into a vim buffer use the 'read from command' command:

```
:r! date
:r! date --date="5 mins"
```

Comment: Unfortunately I am on windows, I have tried a few variants of the windows command `time/T` but I couldn't get the same behavior.