# What's the meaning of `^=` in vimscript?

Tags: vimscript

What's the meaning of `^=` in the following line?

```
set runtimepath^=~/.vim
```

This should be a simple one but I've searched and found nothing. Thanks for your help.

Comment: See: [cursor movement - How do I navigate to topics in Vim's documentation? - Vi and Vim Stack Exchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2136/how-do-i-navigate-to-topics-in-vims-documentation/2137#2137). In this particular case you can just `:help ^=` in vim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prepend `runtimepath` with `~/.vim,`

See `:h :set^=`

```
:se[t] {option}^={value}                *:set^=*
            Multiply the {value} to a number option, or prepend
            the {value} to a string option.  When the option is a
            comma separated list, a comma is added, unless the
            value was empty.
            Also see |:set-args| above.
```

Comment: Actually, `:help ^=` is sufficient.