# Which setting allows me to text wrap whole words instead of letters?

Tags: neovim

At the moment, my width is set to 80.

when a new line starts, it doesn't take the whole word to the next line. Instead, it takes the lagging letters. Which setting changes this behavior?

Comment: do you mean soft wrap (wrap at edge of window) or hard wrap (inserting newlines)

Comment: I think you want `:set linebreak`

Comment: Christian!!!! you are a true gentleman. Can you add this as an answer? I am curious how you would discover this? My struggle with nvim is that I'm not sure which setting does what...

Comment: @Vinn try `:helpgrep`, tab-completion in command line, or searching with `/` in a doc file, or search this forum and find things like [this](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2136/how-do-i-navigate-to-topics-in-vims-documentation) :)

Comment: Super useful @Biggybi - thanks :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`:set linebreak`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27linebreak%27) which will make Vim (soft-)break the lines on whitespace and other characters. To which characters exactly, can be further customized using the ['breakat'](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27breakat%27) setting.

See the help for an extensive description (just follow the links).