# What's the reverse action of ctrl-y?

Tags: vimscript, key-bindings

As title. Just like the case where `<C-n>` and `<C-p>` is a pair. I would like to know how to scroll down one line at a time.

Comment: ctrl+y is't a standard command. I think you have a plugin installed that have implemented ctrl+y for you. And for your other question, scroll down one line should be achievable by pressing j.

Comment: See `:h CTRL-E`

Comment: @MerajulArefinPial I will not call the behavior of `j` "scrolling down". By scrolling down I mean showing one more line at the bottom(and thus hide the first line) of the current window/buffer.

Comment: @MerajulArefinPial `Ctrl-e/y` are even in the original vi. They move the page, not the cursor.

Comment: @paradroid, sorry I was wrong. You are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it might sound hilarious but since there are only a-z keys there to try so I just tried all combinations and found that `<C-e>` is what I need. Thanks to everyone for reading and trying to help in the comment section.

Comment: An easier way to find this out is `:help ctrl-y`, which is in the "scrolling upwards" section, and if you scroll that page up a bit more then there's a "scrolling downwards" section. `:help index` is also useful, and lists all keybinds (`:help normal-index` for normal mode mappings). Also see [How do I navigate to topics in Vim's documentation?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2136/51)